Issues with Receiving Data in NestJS Controller When Integrating with Sentry
I am developing a project that uses Sentry libraries for error tracking and sends them to my local server, which acts as a simplified version of Sentry. The main task of the project is to correctly process requests from Sentry and obtain error data for further analysis.
Problem Description:
I have created a controller in NestJS to handle requests to /api/:projectId/envelope. When I generate an error using myUndefinedFunction(1), Sentry should send data to my server; however, the envelopeData in my controller is coming through empty.
I generate a DSN, and based on this DSN, the projectId is determined as 4. Although the requests reach my server, the headers from Sentry do not arrive, and the envelopeData does not contain any error information.
Here is the code I use to initialize Sentry:
const Sentry = require('@sentry/node');

Sentry.init({
    dsn: 'http://fde473b41d8547c092d69d8eceb2b9bd@127.0.0.1:3000/4',
});

myUndefinedFunction(1);


NestJS Controller Code:
import {
  Controller,
  Post,
  Param,
  Body,
  HttpException,
  HttpStatus,
} from '@nestjs/common';

@Controller('api/:projectId')
export class EnvelopeController {
  @Post('/envelope')
  async handleEnvelope(
    @Param('projectId') projectId: string,
    @Body() envelopeData: any,
  ) {
    try {
      console.log('Received request for projectId:', projectId);
      console.log('Envelope Data:', JSON.stringify(envelopeData, null, 2));

      return { status: 'success', message: 'Envelope processed' };
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error during processing:', error);
      throw new HttpException('BAD REQUEST', HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
  }
}


Logger Middleware:
import { Injectable, NestMiddleware } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';

@Injectable()
export class LoggerMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  use(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    console.log('Request Headers:', req.headers);
    console.log('Request Body:', req.body);
    console.log('Request Path:', req.path);
    
    if (req.body instanceof Buffer) {
      console.log('Request Body (as string):', req.body.toString('utf-8'));
    }

    next();
  }
}

Сonsole output
Request Headers: {
  host: '127.0.0.1:3000',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'transfer-encoding': 'chunked'
}
Request Body: {}
Request Path: /
Get endpoint for projectId: 4
Envelope Data: {}


Questions:

Why are the headers from Sentry not arriving, and why is the data in envelopeData coming through empty, even though the request passes through the middleware and the headers are displayed correctly?
How can I debug and fix this issue to receive error data in envelopeData?

Measures Taken:

I checked that Sentry is correctly initialized with the proper DSN.
I added logging middleware to track the headers and body of the request.

I expect to see this in the console.
{
  exception: { values: [ [Object] ] },
  event_id: 'd5816d366c61412eb92e298638cb308b',
  platform: 'node',
  contexts: {
    trace: {
      trace_id: '89b29266023447e2b9b781b51e226b54',
      span_id: 'bbfc1f0e90ac8c7e'
    },
    runtime: { name: 'node', version: 'v20.12.1' },
    app: {
      app_start_time: '2024-10-09T01:38:45.264Z',
      app_memory: 76492800
    },
    os: {
      kernel_version: '6.8.0-45-generic',
      name: 'Ubuntu Linux',
      version: '22.04'
    },
    device: {
      boot_time: '2024-10-08T22:14:04.737Z',
      arch: 'x64',
      memory_size: 16478691328,
      free_memory: 6089416704,
      processor_count: 12,
      cpu_description: '11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-11400H @ 2.70GHz',
      processor_frequency: 1622
    },
and other fields of the ErrorEvent


It might be because envelopes are not JSON but multiple JSONs separated by newlines.

It's documented here: https://develop.sentry.dev/sdk/envelopes/ here's an example of a tunnel middlewre in C#: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/blob/5450154ffe848f520193e1437a6cd9f5f408fda4/src/Sentry.AspNetCore/SentryTunnelMiddleware.cs

Examples are used for tunneling payloads: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/troubleshooting/#dealing-with-ad-blockers

@LucaForstner
Is there an example of how sentry gives data? It's strange that sentry returns each string/object as JSON. But if this is the case why am I not getting any headers? The documentation doesn't say much about delimiters. I will be very grateful

@BrunoGarcia I really hope that the tunnel middleware will work

I use it on NuGet Trends: https://github.com/dotnet/nuget-trends

@BrunoGarcia Yesss, it works, thank you so much!!! Can you tell me how to parse a string into JSON? Once I do this, I'll post the code here so that others with the same issue can quickly solve it, unlike me, who spent a month reading documentation without results and looking for headers where there were none.
